# keep searching until limit is reached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a search in place that finds all 3 matching categories, all 2 categories, and all 1 categories like the below.

```
def self.three_matching_cat(rel)
  cats = rel.prefs.map {|p| p.category_id}
  self.where(:category_id => cats).group(:name).having("count(*) >2").map {|p| p.name}    
end
```

What I want to do is limit the total number of results to 10, but want to make sure that all the results with 3 matching categories returned and to only continue searching until a total of 10 results are found.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I ended up doing is just added up all the arrays and then sliced it.  ie:

```
(a + b + c)[0,10].uniq
```

Comment: I've used this approach to solve this type of problem in the past but I'm still curious about a better way to do this.